# tengo varios inputs que quiero llenar con JavaScript pero algunos no se llenan y no entiendo porque

Tags: javascript, php, input, html-tabla

Tengo el siguiente script, el cual es una consulta ajax que me envia contenido a otro documento php, tengo mas contenido que este, pero este es el bloque que no me funciona correctamente, ya que algunos inputs no se estan llenando con los datos que tiene la variable php.

```
// Asignar los valores a las variables correspondientes
                    $ult_pago_CP = $firstRow['fecultpag'];
                    $monto_CP = number_format($firstRow['monto'], 2, '.', ',');
                    $saldo_final_CP = number_format($firstRow['sfinal'], 2, '.', ',');
                    $t_interes_CP = number_format($firstRow['total_int'], 2, '.', ',');
                    //$t_interes_CP = $firstRow['total_int'];
                    $t_capital_CP = number_format($firstRow['total_cap'], 2, '.', ',');
                    $t_mora_CP = number_format($firstRow['total_mora'], 2, '.', ',');
                    $t_otros_CP = number_format($firstRow['total_otros'], 2, '.', ',');
                    $t_seguro_CP = number_format($firstRow['total_seguro'], 2, '.', ',');
                    $plazo_de_CP = number_format($firstRow['plazo'], 2, '.', ',');
                    $plazo_po_CP = number_format($firstRow['plazo'], 2, '.', ',');
                    $total_pag_CP = number_format($firstRow['total_pag'], 2, '.', ',');

                    // Mostrar los valores en los campos de entrada
                        $int_cargado_CP = $dataFill['sumintcarg'];
                        $cap_cargado_CP = $dataFill['sumcapcarg'];
                        $mora_cargado_CP = $firstRow['mora'];
                        $otros_cargado_CP = $dataFill['sumotroscarg'];
                        $seg_cargado_CP = $dataFill['sumsegcarg']; 
                        $cargado_CP = $dataFill['totalcargado'];
                        $balance_CP = $dataFillFull['totalcargado'];
                        $salda_hoy_CP = $dataFillFull['sumcapcarg'] + $dataFill['sumintcarg'] + $dataFill['sumsegcarg'] + $dataFillPrestamoFull['sumtototros'] + $dataFillPrestamoFull['summora'];
                        $atrasos_CP = $cargado_CP;
                        $capital_r_CP = $dataFillFull['sumcapcarg'];
                        echo "<h1>".$salda_hoy_CP."</h1>"
                        
                ?>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById('ult_pago_CP').value = "<?php echo $ult_pago_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('monto_CP').value = "<?php echo $monto_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('saldo_final_CP').value = "<?php echo $saldo_final_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('t_interes_CP').value = "<?php echo $t_interes_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('t_capital_CP').value = "<?php echo $t_capital_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('t_mora_CP').value = "<?php echo $t_mora_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('t_otros_CP').value = "<?php echo $t_otros_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('t_seguro_CP').value = "<?php echo $t_seguro_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('plazo_de_CP').value = "<?php echo $plazo_de_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('plazo_po_CP').value = "<?php echo $plazo_po_CP; ?>";

                        document.getElementById('cap_cargado_CP').value = "<?php echo $cap_cargado_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('mora_cargado_CP').value = "<?php echo $mora_cargado_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('otros_cargado_CP').value = "<?php echo $otros_cargado_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('seg_cargado_CP').value = "<?php echo $seg_cargado_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('int_cargado_CP').value = "<?php echo $int_cargado_CP; ?>";
                        document.getElementById('cargado_CP').value = "<?php echo $cargado_CP; ?>";
                        
                        document.getElementById('balance_CP').value = "<?php echo $balance_CP ?>";
                        document.getElementById('salda_hoy_CP').value = "<?php echo $salda_hoy_CP ?>";
                        document.getElementById('atrasos_CP').value = "<?php echo $atrasos_CP ?>";
                        document.getElementById('capital_r_CP').value = "<?php echo $capital_r_CP ?>";

                    </script>
                <?php 
    }
```

ya confirme que los datos estan llegando, y en algunos inputs como los "..._cargado_CP" pero en los input como saldo_final, balance, etc.

estos son los inputs que tengo en un documentos php(el javascript se envia por una consulta ajax)

```
<table class="inputs-consulta-prestamos">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="94" class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Utt_pago</td>
                        <td width="144"><input type="text" class="textInput" id="ult_pago_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td width="63" class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Monto</td>
                        <td width="144"><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="monto_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td width="81" class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Cargado</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="int_cargado_CP " placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td width="60" class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Pagado</td>
                        <td width="144"><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="cargado_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td width="74" class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Pagadas</td>
                        <td width="173" class="d-flex">
                            <input name="" type="text" class="numberInput" style="width: 40px!important; margin: 0;" placeholder="0.00" disabled>
                            <div style="margin-right: 3px;">De:</div>
                            <input name="Input" type="text" class="numberInput" id="plazo_de_CP" style="width: 41.5px!important;" placeholder="0" disabled />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Estatus</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Vacio" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Saldo final</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="saldo_final_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Interes Carg.</td>
                        <td width="144"><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="int_cargado_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">T_interes</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="t_interes_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Atrazadas</td>
                        <td class="d-flex">
                            <input name="text" class="numberInput" type="text" style="width: 40px!important;  margin: 0;" placeholder="0.00" disabled />
                            P.O:
                            <input type="text" class="numberInput" id="plazo_po_CP" style="width: 41px!important;" placeholder="0" disabled>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Estado</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Vacio" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Balance</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Capital Carg.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="cap_cargado_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">T_capital</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="t_capital_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">P_Sgte_Cta</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" placeholder="0.00" style="width: 100px!important;" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">F_Vence</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="f_vence_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Salda hoy</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="int_cargado_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Mora. Carg.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="mora_cargado_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">T_mora</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="t_mora_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Tipo prest.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Vacio" style="width: 100px!important;" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Int.sob.corte</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Atrasos</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Otros Carg.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="otros_cargado_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">T_otros</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="t_otros_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Tipos plazo</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Vacio" style="width: 100px!important;" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Int. Adelantado</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Capital R.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Seguro Carg.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="seg_cargado_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">T_Seguro</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="numberInput" id="t_seguro_CP" placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                        <td class="texto-consulta-prestamos">Tipo divisa</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Vacio" style="width: 100px!important;" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: No deberías tener multiples elementos con el mismo `id`. Al buscar por `id` solo vas a obtener 1, el primero. PD: hay un elemento que tiene un espacio en su `id`, dice, `id="int_cargado_CP "`

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593142/21) podría servirte.